# How to pass config parameter 'url' to Strapi running in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, strapi

At https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations.html, there is a config parameter 'url' to set the public URL of the server.

Is there a way to pass a value for that 'url' parameter when running Strapi in a Docker container?

Maybe via the environment variables in the docker-compose.yml?

```
version: '3'
services:
  strapi:
    image: strapi/strapi
    environment:
      DATABASE_CLIENT: mysql
      DATABASE_HOST: mysql
      DATABASE_PORT: 3306
      DATABASE_NAME: strapi
      DATABASE_USERNAME: strapi
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: strapi
      DATABASE_SSL: 'false'
    volumes:
      - ./app:/srv/app
    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the server configuration on my local machine (not in the docker container) at /app/config/server.js and added a value for 'url' there:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  url: env('PUBLIC_URL', 'https://example.com/strapi'),
  admin: {
    auth: {
      secret: env('ADMIN_JWT_SECRET', 'mysecret'),
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: The correct way is to just create a `.env` file in the project's root directory. As you can see the config files have a `env` argument. This is used for reading all variables from the .env file automatically. So just create a `.env` file which will be carried over to the docker container and put all the variables in it. ex. `PUBLIC_URL=https://example.com/strapi`